# minimax and transformations

Tags: estimation, robust

for two real random $n$-vector $y$ and $x$ 
and a random $n$-vector $e$ with distribution 
$F$ independent of $x$ we know (1) that the 
estimator

$$\text{med}\left( \frac{y_i}{x_i}\right)$$

is minimax estimator for $\alpha$ in the model:

$$y_i=\alpha x_i+e_i$$

My question is the following: does this 
result implies that the estimator

$$\text{med}\left( y_i x_i\right)$$

is minimax estimator for $\alpha$ in the model

$$y_i=\alpha/x_i+e_i$$

> (1) Martin,R.D. Yohai, V.J. and Zamar,R.H., Mini-max bias, robust
>   regression. Ann. Stat. (1989)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Let $z_i = 1/x_i$. Use the initial result on the model $y_i=\alpha z_i + e_i$, for which all assumptions seem to be satisfied, and you get the result you want.